# argocd failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1 error with helm repo

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm, argocd, argocd-notification

I'm encountering an issue with ArgoCD and Helm. I'm trying to add a Helm virtual repository from JFrog registry. Sometimes, ArgoCD  is able to add the repository, but other times it's giving me the following error:

`ComparisonError: Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =` helm repo add --username ****** --password ****** --pass-credentials helm-virtual-repo <repo-url>`failed timeout after 1m30s`
I have read many articles and blogs, but I have not found a specific solution.
Could anyone please help me troubleshoot this problem?

I am trying to add a Helm virtual repository and with argocd sync I am getting an error